Upgrading MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0 failed due to `Certificate not found: rds-ca-2015`, how to fix?
I am manually Upgrading MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0 in my RDS Console.
following this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html

However I am facing and Issue when I press the modify Db Instance button. it produce the error Certificate not found: rds-ca-2015

Does someone has insights about how to solve this and allow the MySQL upgrade to proceed ?

Before proceeding, create a snapshot of the RDS cluster. If a failure occurs during an upgrade, it is difficult to restore.
The above problem appears to be a certificate-related issue. rds-ca-2015 will expire soon. Therefore, please change the certificate to the rds-ca-2048(?) version and try again.

After hitting the same issue and seeing that no one else responded with a satisfactory answer, I'll add one:
The error arises from trying to modify an out of date certificate while also trying to simultaneously make other changes. You will need to update the certificate only as a first step and can then make the other modifications as needed once that is complete. I wasn't able to do this through the web UI, but I was able to do so via the CLI with a command like the following:
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier <INSTANCE> --ca-certificate-identifier <NEW_CERT> --apply-immediately --region <REGION>

